# WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value redis

Tags: redis

When I directly run the below GET command in my redis cloud,

```
GET 1000:125:1603875000
```

I am getting error

> WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value redis

When I check

```
type 1000:125:1603875000
```

gives me
Hash

But if I execute SET before Get, like this

```
SET 1000:125:1603875000 11
```

I get "11" on executing GET command.

Why does the string is considered as Hash? How can I execute GET with the specified string.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you RUN  'SET 1000:125:1603875000' to 11, you are overwriting the initial '1000:125:1603875000' which was a hash and once you set '1000:125:1603875000' as '11' you can run a GET command to get the value of the key.

To get the value of a redis hash you can run HGETALL to get all the values in the hash or HGET KEYNAME to get a specific key of the hash.

To illustrate the use of these commands:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET employee name Ankit
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> GET employee
(error) WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL employee
1) "name"
2) "Ankit"
127.0.0.1:6379> HGET employee name
"Ankit"
127.0.0.1:6379> SET employee Ankit
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> GET employee
"Ankit"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```